# Split returned data into equal 3 div columns

Tags: php

I am trying to display data from my database using divs. I wanted to split the returned data into 3 columns as of now I can only split the data into 2 columns.

```
$column = '<div class="col-lg-6">';
$modulecounter = 0;

$moduletotalquery = "SELECT COUNT(MODULEID) AS MODULEID FROM ASMODULERIGHTS";
$moduletotalsql = oci_parse($conn, $moduletotalquery);
oci_execute($moduletotalsql);
$moduletotalrow = oci_fetch_array($moduletotalsql);

$modulequery = "SELECT MODULEID, MODULEDESC FROM ASMODULERIGHTS ORDER BY MODULEID";
$modulesql = oci_parse($conn, $modulequery);
$moduleexec = oci_execute($modulesql);

if($moduleexec){
    while($modulerow = oci_fetch_array($modulesql)){
        $modulecounter++;
        $moduleid = "m". $modulecounter;

        $column .= '<div class="col-lg-auto">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input modulerights" id="'. $moduleid .'">
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="'. $moduleid .'">'. $modulerow['MODULEDESC'] .'</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>';

       if ($modulecounter == floor($moduletotalrow['MODULEID'] / 2)) {
            $column .= '</div><div class="col-lg-6">';
       }
    }
}

$column .= '</div>';

echo $column;
```

Comment: @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie no errors but it is only returning 1 row

Comment: Changed code a bit: https://3v4l.org/DmEGe  . But i am clueless why it is returning 1 row only. Check it now

Comment: @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie there is still one tiny problem each row is coated with <div class="col-lg-6"> that should not be the case. only add <div class="col-lg-6"> when dividing the data into 3 for example if there are 30 data there should only be 3 <div class="col-lg-6">

Comment: my code is working fine:- https://3v4l.org/TlJT2  unable to understand

Comment: @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie sorry I traced the problem it is working now thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide data into chunks and then add `<div>` to chunks:

```
<?php

$modulecounter = 0;
$moduletotalquery = "SELECT COUNT(MODULEID) AS MODULEID FROM ASMODULERIGHTS";
$moduletotalsql = oci_parse($conn, $moduletotalquery);
oci_execute($moduletotalsql);
$moduletotalrow = oci_fetch_array($moduletotalsql);

$modulequery = "SELECT MODULEID, MODULEDESC FROM ASMODULERIGHTS ORDER BY MODULEID";
$modulesql = oci_parse($conn, $modulequery);
$moduleexec = oci_execute($modulesql);

$nrows = oci_fetch_all($modulesql, $res, null, null, OCI_FETCHSTATEMENT_BY_ROW+OCI_ASSOC);

$column = '';
if(count($nrows) > 0){
    $divideCount = ceil(count($nrows)/3);

    $results = array_chunk($res ,$divideCount);
    foreach($results as $result){
        $column .= '<div class="col-lg-6">';
        foreach($result as $res){
            $modulecounter++;
            $moduleid = "m". $modulecounter;

            $column .= '<div class="col-lg-auto">
                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input modulerights" id="'. $moduleid .'">
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="'. $moduleid .'">'. $res['MODULEDESC'] .'</label>
                </div>
            </div>';
        }

        $column .= '</div>';
    }

}

echo $column;
```

Sample output:- https://3v4l.org/TlJT2

Answer (score 0):

The truth is: I've never used Oracle before nor have I ever answered an Oracle question, but a quick glance over the php manual tells me that the original post is doing too many queries and Anant's answer simply will not work as posted.

Here is a script that uses modulus calculations to determine if a new column should be created. If the modulus calculation evaluates as zero, a new column is required.  If `$i` is zero, then there is not yet a column to close because it is the first iteration of the loop. If there are any rows in the result set, the loop will not close the final column -- this is conditionally done after the loop finishes.

```
$stmt = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT MODULEID, MODULEDESC FROM ASMODULERIGHTS ORDER BY MODULEID");
oci_execute($stmt);
$count = oci_fetch_all($stmt, $result, 0, -1, OCI_FETCHSTATEMENT_BY_ROW);
$maxPerColumn = ceil($count / 3);
$output = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i) {
    if (!($i % $maxPerColumn)) {
        if ($i) {
            $output .= '</div>';
        }
        $output .= '<div class="col-lg-4">';
    }
    $output .= '<div class="col-lg-auto">
                    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input modulerights" id="m'. $i .'">
                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="m'. $i .'">' . $result[$i]['MODULEDESC'] . '</label>
                    </div>
                </div>';
}
if ($count) {
    $output .= '</div>';
}
echo $output;
```

Using `array_chunk()` may be a more attractive solution for some developers despite the inner loop because there is conditional logic to understand. Notice that the `$i` counter is lost and that MODULEID is used for simplicity instead

```
$output = '';
foreach (array_chunk($result, ceil($count / 3)) as $group) {
    $output .= '<div class="col-lg-4">';
    foreach ($group as $row) {
        $output .= '<div class="col-lg-auto">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input modulerights" id="m'. $row['MODULEID'] .'">
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="m'. $row['MODULEID'] .'">' . $row['MODULEDESC'] . '</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>';
    }
    $output .= '</div>';
}
echo $output;
```

Bootstrap columns have a total width of 12, so each of the 3 columns should use 4 in the class declaration.