# How to correctly generate the chapter design structure and its video series?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

The following method works perfectly, it correctly generates the following HTML structure, you can see it in the following link: https://jsfiddle.net/L6wo42ar/

```
$id_course = 1;

$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT id_chapter, chapter
                        FROM tbl_chapters
                        WHERE id_course=?
                        ");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $id_course);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
if ($stmt->num_rows>0) {

    $stmt->bind_result($id_chapter, $chapter);

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {

        $stmtA = $con->prepare("SELECT preview,
                            title_video,
                            description_video,
                            type_format,
                            multimedia,
                            detail,
                            time_video,
                            url_website
                        FROM tbl_videos
                        WHERE id_course=? AND id_chapter=?
                        ");
        $stmtA->bind_param("ii", $id_course, $id_chapter);
        $stmtA->execute();
        $stmtA->store_result();
        if ($stmtA->num_rows>0) {

            $stmtA->bind_result($preview, $title_video, $description_video, $type_format, $multimedia, $detail, $time_video, $url_website);


        $Div = '<div class="modules">
            <button class="accordion">'.$chapter.'</button>';
        $Nav = '<div id="enlaces" class="section videolist" style="display: none;">';
            while ($stmtA->fetch()) {

                //if($type_format === 'video') {
                    $Nav.='<a class="link playing" href="#">
                        <div class="chapter flex">
                            <div><span class="check-mark"></span></div>
                            <div><span class="play-title-course">'.$title_video.'</span></div>
                            <div><span class="time-video">'.$time_video.'</span></div>
                        </div>
                    </a>';
                //}

            }
        }

        $Nav .= '</div></div>';
        echo $Div;
        echo $Nav;
    }
}
```

So since I needed to generate that same structure and my proposed code generates it the same without problems, here you can see the result: https://jsfiddle.net/L6wo42ar/

Now the question is that I am avoiding making a query within a cycle, for this I combine both tables resulting in the following:

```
$id_course = 1;

$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT c.chapter,
                            v.preview,
                            v.title_video,
                            v.description_video,
                            v.type_format,
                            v.multimedia,
                            v.detail,
                            v.time_video,
                            v.url_website
                        FROM tbl_chapters c
                        JOIN tbl_videos v ON v.id_course = c.id_course AND v.id_chapter = c.id_chapter
                        WHERE c.id_course=?
                        ");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $id_course);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
if ($stmt->num_rows>0) {

    $stmt->bind_result($chapter, $preview, $title_video, $description_video, $type_format, $multimedia, $detail, $time_video, $url_website);

    $tempChapter = "";
    $i = 1;

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {

        if ($tempChapter != $chapter) {

            $Div = '<div class="modules">
            <button class="accordion">'.$chapter.'</button>';
            $Nav = '<div id="enlaces" class="section videolist" style="display: none;">';

            echo $Div;

            $tempChapter = $chapter;
        }

        //if($type_format === 'video') {
            $Nav.='<a class="link playing" href="#">
                    <div class="chapter flex">
                        <div><span class="check-mark"></span></div>
                        <div><span class="play-title-course">'.$title_video.'</span></div>
                        <div><span class="time-video">'.$time_video.'</span></div>
                    </div>
                </a>';
        //}
        
        $Nav .= '</div></div>';

        echo $Nav;
    }

} else {
    echo "no data!";
}
```

I knew that I was going to have problems especially with the subject of the title of the chapter that was going to be repeated due to the number of records in the video table, in the end I solved it as follows:

```
if ($tempChapter != $chapter) {
    echo $chapter;
    $tempChapter = $chapter; 
}
```

But, here is the problem that the HTML structure is generating wrong, here the result: https://jsfiddle.net/3Lfgbpkc/

Can you explain how to solve this error?

Comment: As an aside, I don't see any benefit in `if ($stmt->num_rows>0) {` since you are using `while()`.  Do you see that `$Nav .= '</div></div>';` is unconditionally added, but the opening divs are only conditionally added?  We have duplicates of this kind of question.

Comment: @mickmackusa I had added it to later show a message when there is no data, for example: We are adding new updated content, come back soon!

Comment: You need to conditionally close divs as needed and unconditionally close the last div after the loop is finished.  Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60644056/2943403

Comment: @mickmackusa I know, but I have already tried to move around and, it does not work, I think I will have to use the code that uses query within the cycle: /

Comment: @mickmackusa The problem is generated by the title of the chapter, because if not the result was another, as in my first code I did everything concatenated without problems and without errors.

Comment: @Valentina try my answer

Comment: @Val be sure to use `ORDER BY id_chapter` so that your rows are grouped together as you iterate.

Comment: @mickmackusa friend that does not imply the correct design of the HTML structure.

Comment: @IndraKumarS I will review it thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid your confusions, Simply create an array of chapters and its videos like this

```
$chapters = array();

  while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $chapters[$chapter][] = array(
                            "title" => $title_video,
                          "time" => $time_video
                          );

  }
```

Your `$chapters` array will be like this,

[image]

Then use this function to print the html contents

```
printChapters($chapters);

function printChapters($chapters) {
    foreach ($chapters as $chapter => $videos) {
       echo '<div class="modules">
            <button class="accordion">'.$chapter.'</button>
            <div id="enlaces" class="section videolist" style="display: none;">';
           
            foreach ($videos as $key => $video) {
               echo '<a class="link playing" href="#">
                      <div class="chapter flex">
                        <div><span class="check-mark"></span></div>
                        <div><span class="play-title-course">'.$video["title"].'</span></div>
                        <div><span class="time-video">'.$video["time"].'</span></div>
                      </div>
                    </a>';
            }
                    
                        
         echo   '</div>                
          </div>';
    }

}
```